# How to set value gap on Y-axis using Python library matplotlib.pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/weCny.png)I am trying to plot a bar graph on powerBi using python and i am expecting values on y-axis after the interval of 10 for example 0-10,10-20 upto 100. But in actual it is showing after interval of 25, like 0-25, 26-50 and so on

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ax=plt.gca()

#dataset.plot(kind='bar',x='Day',y='Feed_Req_to_Standard',ax=ax) 

dataset.plot(kind='bar',x='Day',y=['Feed_%Diff_From_Stand','Feed_Req_to_Standard'], color=['red','green'],ax=ax)

plt.ylim(bottom= -100, top= 100)
plt.xlabel('Days')

plt.show()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1wNt.png)

Comment: please attach your images within the question, and not as hyperlinks

Answer (score 0):

You can set the tick locations and labels on the y axis using the function `matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_yticks()`. If you want to take a closer look, [here is the documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_yticks.html).
Applied to your problem, it would probably be applied like this (note I haven't tested it though as I don't have access to your data).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.axes import Axes

spacing = 10
ticks = [spacing*i for i in range(5)] # gets ticks values
Axes.set_yticks(ticks)
ax=plt.gca()

dataset.plot(kind='bar',x='Day',y=['Feed_%Diff_From_Stand','Feed_Req_to_Standard'], color=['red','green'],ax=ax)

plt.ylim(bottom= -100, top= 100)
plt.xlabel('Days')

plt.show()
```